# I want to show a csv file populating on the screen while my model written in python is running to show how my model is working to non-programmers

Tags: python, csv

I did this years ago with ARENA, but I can't duplicated it in Python.

The results don't show in the csv until you open and close the file. I can't find anything on this problem.

```py
with open(file_name, mode='a') as file_object:
    print(result, file=file_object, flush = True)
```

I want the csv file to remain open on the screen and each row appear as the python writes to the file. For non-programmers it makes the model feel a little less like a black box.

Comment: Are you using `print(result, file=file_object, flush = True)` to write to the file? In any case, why not print the CSV to stdout?

Comment: Yes. I am using the print statement to write to the CSV file.  I have the CSV open in Excel and it doesn't show the result(a single Float number).  If I close the file and open it the results are in the file.  I found that if business people see the results populating in a spreadsheet, in which they are familiar, they understand the models better.

Comment: _Yes. I am using the print statement to write to the CSV file._ Why, though? It works, it just seems unusual.

Comment: In any case, you might be better off using something like xlwings to interact with Excel itself, rather than with the file.

Comment: Thanks.  I will look at the xlwings.  First look it might be what I need.

Comment: xlwings works great for what I need.  Thanks for the help.